# How can I Install oh-my-zsh

Tags: laravel-5.1, oh-my-zsh

Can I ask some help how can install this in windows 10 [oh-my-zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/)

Are there any prerequisite on this?

Comment: Please look at this post on how to run or install shell scripts. http://superuser.com/questions/120045/how-to-execute-sh-file-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use `oh-my-zsh` is to use linux based OS on [WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).

If you download [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/wsl) or Linux based Operating system in windows 10/11 WSL2. Then you can use any terminal app that can be run on Linux. So this is also an way to install zsh with `oh-my-zsh`.

If you want something similar as `oh-my-zsh` for Powershell you can try [`oh-my-posh`](https://ohmyposh.dev/).

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not have `bash` or `zsh` but I will still try to answer your question. This is nearly impossible to do something like installing `oh-my-zsh` without terminal utility. But I found [Babun](http://babun.github.io/) which is mostly similar to that. It has a pre-configured cygwin and integrated `oh-my-zsh`. So you may get your hands dirty with that.